# CUDA on nvidia rtx 2060 Max-Q (455.45.01 driver) not working in linux

Tags: c++, cuda

I'm trying to compile a simple code from nvidia's website using CUDA 11.1 and driver 455.45.01 for the 2060 Max-Q GPU but I get a segmentation fault error, I tried this on arch and linux mint.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
// Kernel function to add the elements of two arrays
__global__
void add(int n, float *x, float *y)
{
 for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
 y[i] = x[i] + y[i];
}

int main(void)
{
int N = 1<<20;
float *x, *y;

// Allocate Unified Memory – accessible from CPU or GPU
cudaMallocManaged(&x, N*sizeof(float));
cudaMallocManaged(&y, N*sizeof(float));

// initialize x and y arrays on the host
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
x[i] = 1.0f;
y[i] = 2.0f;
}

// Run kernel on 1M elements on the GPU
add<<<1, 1>>>(N, x, y);

// Wait for GPU to finish before accessing on host
cudaDeviceSynchronize();

// Check for errors (all values should be 3.0f)
float maxError = 0.0f;
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
maxError = fmax(maxError, fabs(y[i]-3.0f));
std::cout << "Max error: " << maxError << std::endl;

// Free memory
cudaFree(x);
cudaFree(y);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You must check support for `cudaDevAttrManagedMemory` prior to allocating managed memory and check results of `cudaMallocManaged`.

Comment: I did cout<<cudaDevAttrManagedMemory<<endl; and I got 83, I'm not sure if I'm doing this right.

Comment: I got "the provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain" for cudaMallocManaged

Comment: That error code might be an indication of a broken CUDA install, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65413429/cuda-complains-about-nvcc-being-an-unsupported-toolchain).

Comment: yes it was, I tried a few versions of cuda and finally got it to work using cuda 11.1.1. Thanks!