# CUDA complains about nvcc being an "unsupported toolchain"

Tags: cuda

I've made a 1D convolution program in CUDA - but for some reason the executable doesn't run as CUDA complains "the provided PTX was compiled with an unsupported toolchain" (this error is thrown on the first CUDA library function). My program was compiled with nvcc, with the command I used being exactly: `nvcc program.cu -o program` and the command I used to run the resultant executable: `./program`.
Googling returns little to no results - any help?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### tl;dr: NVIDIA driver too old for CUDA toolkit

The NVIDIA driver version in the Arch repos was out-of-date with the newest CUDA version in the same repos - (https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-toolkit-release-notes/index.html, my system had CUDA version 11.2.0, but NVIDIA Driver version 455.x.x).

Downgrading the CUDA version solved the issue.